# ArcPy mxd.save() not overwriting MXD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcmap, mxd

I am using an ArcPy code to find and replace the data source of layers in a series of MXDs using lyr.replaceDataSource as follows:

```
import arcpy
import os
mxdfolder =r'C:\Folder' #folder in which mxd's are stored
for root, folder, files in os.walk(mxdfolder):
   for file in files:
       fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
       if os.path.isfile(fullname) and file.endswith('.mxd'):
             mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullname)
             for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
                 if str(lyr.name)=="original_layer": # name of layer to be replaced
                    print("layer found")
                    lyr.replaceDataSource(r'"C:/geodatabase.gdb", "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE" "new_layer") #geodatabase layer is stored in, and new layer to replace old layer
                    print("layer replaced")
                    mxd.save()
                    del mxd
```

I used this code the other week and it worked perfectly. However, I have made some further changes to my MXD layer names, and now when I run the code, it doesn't appear to work. The code runs as expected, printing "layer found", "layer replaced", as it works through the list of MXD's in the folder. There are no error codes or any suggestions that the code has failed. However, when I check the MXDs after the code has finished, none of the layers have actually been replaced, suggesting that it is not saving/overwriting the MXDs at the end. Has anyone had this experience, or can see what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import arcpy
import os
mxdfolder =r'C:\Folder' #folder in which mxd's are stored
for root, folder, files in os.walk(mxdfolder):
    for file in files:
    fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
    if os.path.isfile(fullname) and file.endswith('.mxd'):
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullname)
        for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
            if str(lyr.name)=="original_layer": # name of layer to be replaced
                print("layer found")
                lyr.replaceDataSource(r'C:/geodatabase.gdb', "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE","new_layer") #geodatabase layer is stored in, and new layer to replace old layer
                print("layer replaced")
        mxd.save()
        del mxd
```